# Laravel Event not firing inside a listener

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have an event say `EventA`. with a handler `HandlerA`. Inside `HandlerA`, if a specific case is met, i'm trying to fire `EventB`. Unfortunately `EventB` is never getting fired.

I tried to fire `EventB` inside a controller and it worked just fine.

Is this a bug / is this supposed be like this / am i doing something wrong?

I'm using Laravel 5.1.

Thank you

Comment: can you post your listener?